# Symfony form relation collection : a way to avoid creating another class?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I work on a project with a lot of forms. 
Almost all of them are made for an entity A and some fields on a related entity B (one to many : A contains multiple B).

I can make all my forms with 2 classes for each form : the "primary" type, related to some fields of A, and a secondary type for the fields I need from entities B for that form, used int the primary type via a CollectionType.

Basic example :

```
$builder->add('BcollectionFieldInA', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => BTypeForSomeFields::class, 
]);
```

I have to make this FormType for entity A of course, but I was wondering if :

Is there a way to avoid having to do another class for B fields (BTypeForSomeFields::class in the example). It is not a big problem but creating always (minimum) 2 types for a form is adding a useless complexity. I know that my secondary types for B fields will never be reused, and sometimes it will be just for one simple text field !

Comment: You are probably looking for the `property_path`-option. Instead of creating a new form class for B you can add those fields from B to the original form and then use `property_path` to signify where the value should be mapped to. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path

Comment: Alternatively you can have a more elaborate mapping with [Data Mappers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html)

Comment: If you B field is always a collection then just stick with creating a second class.  The work arounds will probably be harder to maintain than one additional class.  You might take a step back and ask yourself why your project requires so many different forms.

Comment: Ok I guess I have all the ways now and the choice is up to me, thanks you both !